# control not found message is displayed

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radwindow

```
Error Message displayed as "AddFavoriteRadWindow not found"
```

**My code:**

```
protected void btnAddReport_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
         this.form1.Controls.Add(AddFavoriteRadWindow); // working fine
    }

protected void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtReportFavorite.Text != string.Empty)
    {
        // code for inserting into db..
        AddFavoriteRadWindow.Visible = false; // not working 
    }
}
```

"AddFavoriteRadWindow not found" message is displayed when I want to hide the rad window

Comment: You may put the code where you have defined: `AddFavoriteRadWindow` in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the instance of your added controls from your Control Collection. Try

```
(this.form1.FindControl(AddFavoriteRadWindow.ID) as RadWindow).Visible = false;
```

You may put a check in place against null. Something like.

```
if((this.form1.FindControl(AddFavoriteRadWindow.ID) as RadWindow) != null)
```

*(I am not sure about your class name, I have used `RadWindow` but you can replace that with your class name)*

EDIT: You should pass the string `id` of the control in your FindControl method to get that specific control back

Comment: My class name is Reports. .Find is not populated. Thanks.

Comment: 'System.Web.UI.ControlCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Find' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.ControlCollection' could be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) message is displayed. Thanks.

Comment: @SOUser, my bad, it should have been `FindControl()`, I have edited the answer as well.

Comment: Now, it is throwing error message as "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.". Thanks.

Comment: @SOUser, please add in your question where you are defining `AddFavoriteRadWindow`